# What is difference between '*' and 'html, body' as a selector in CSS syntax?

Tags: css, css-selectors

What's difference between following the two selectors?

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: and don't you think that this answer can be found by an easy google search ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`*` selects **everything**, including tags, classes, ids and eveything you can think of.

`html, body` only selects the body and the html tags.

Comment: The reason why 'html, body' are applied to other elements is due to 'inheritance'